# multiple notifications in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, notifications, mpmovieplayercontroller

Is it possible to have two different playback notifications in a MPMoviePlayerController?

I want to use these:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:self.moviePlayer];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidChange:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                                           object:self.moviePlayer];
```

i did manage to get them working but when i use them together only `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification` is called.

Please advise.

Comment: Both of these notifications are intended to be used together. The situations for which they should be used can be found out from  documentation of [these notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953-CH3-DontLinkElementID_3).

Comment: I also found the documentation and i have implemented the methods but when my movie has ended it sends a    MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused instead of a    MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification when i use both notifications methods

Comment: Are you by any chance exiting fullscreen mode by clicking Done button or programmatically when movie playback completes?

Comment: no the video stays in fullscreen. What i am trying to achieve is when the video is paused, a menu pops up and when the video ends it must go to another page.